# Castle windsor wire generic irepository with 2 types

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, castle-windsor, irepository

Hi I am trying to change a code example found here 
http://imar.spaanjaars.com/577/aspnet-n-layered-applications-implementing-a-repository-using-ef-code-first-part-5

In his example he uses structure map, when I converted it to windsor I can get it to work with the one repository using the following.

```
        container.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWorkFactory>().ImplementedBy<EFUnitOfWorkFactory>(),
            Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<EFUnitOfWork>(),
            Component.For<Model.Repositories.IPeopleRepository>().ImplementedBy<PeopleRepository>().LifestyleTransient());
```

But what I really want to do is to map all the irepository based interfacees to thier implementation. 
Here is the IRepository, T is the entity, K is the prmiary key type

```
public interface IRepository<T, K> where T : class
{
}
```

Its implementation Is

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T, int>, IDisposable where T :      DomainEntity<int>
{
}
```

My controller has the interface IPeopleRepository as a constructor paramerter.

```
public interface IPeopleRepository : IRepository<Person, int>
{
}

public class PeopleRepository : Repository<Person>, IPeopleRepository
{
}
```

I want to have one register to register all repositories, something like this, but it wont match and i get the error Service 'Spaanjaars.ContactManager45.Model.Repositories.IPeopleRepository' which was not registered

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<,>))
                             .ImplementedBy(typeof(Repository<>))
                             .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

What am i missing in regards to this? is it because my irepository has 2 generic types?

Answer (score 1):

In order to map all the IRepository based interfaces to their implementations **.WithService.AllInterfaces()** should be used.

This registration should solve your issue.

```
container.Register(
    Classes.FromThisAssembly()
        .BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<,>))
        .WithService.AllInterfaces()
        .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

There are some tests to test it. I claim they are green.

```
[TestClass]
public class InstallerTest
{
    private IWindsorContainer container;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new Installer());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ResilveTest_ResolvesViaIRepository()
    {
        // act
        var repository = container.Resolve<IRepository<Person, int>>();
        // assert
        repository.Should().BeOfType<PeopleRepository>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ResilveTest_ResolvesViaIPeopleRepository()
    {
        // act
        var repository = container.Resolve<IPeopleRepository>();
        // assert
        repository.Should().BeOfType<PeopleRepository>();
    }
}

public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<,>))
                .WithService.AllInterfaces()
                .LifestylePerThread());
    }
}
```